# Как создать анимацию в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Подскажите, как запустить анимацию пушки во время выстрела ядра из нее? Создание и выстрел ядра у меня происходит в методе Shoot(). Не понимаю как запустить анимацию во время срабатывания Shoot().

```
private void Update() {
    if (Target != null) {
        if (reloadTimer > 0) reloadTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (reloadTimer <= 0)
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        else { Target = SortObj(); }
    } 
} 

void Shoot()
{
    GameObject patronGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(patronPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    Bullet patron = patronGO.GetComponent<Bullet>();  
    if (patron != null)
        patron.Finder(Target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко - вам в коде нужна ссылка на компонент Animator Controller, который висит на пушке. В самом аниматоре должны быть настроены переходы между анимациями по определённым условиям. Например, если есть триггер Shoot, то нужно проиграть анимацию ShootAnimation.

После чего из кода вам нужно делать `_animator.SetTrigger("Shoot");` в момент выстрела, где _animator - ссылка на компонент аниматора пушки.

На самом деле тема комплексная и полный ответ будет довольно велик. Поэтому советую вам посмотреть короткий ролик от Unity, в котором они [учат из кода управлять аниматором](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-scripting).

Там есть субтитры, которые довольно качественно переводятся встроенными средствами на русский язык. Да и без субтитров вполне можно смотреть, просто повторяя действия из ролика.